# Which LaTeX font has the number 1 as a straight line?

Tags: fonts

I am writing some homework for young children, and find they write the number "1" a lot like the number "7" because of typical font styles (such as this one!).

Does anyone out there know of a font in which the number "1" is a straight line?

Comment: This one is pretty close: http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/gfsneohellenic/ and this one: http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/baskervillef/ and this one: http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/stix/ and this: http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/txfonts/ or this one: http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/ebgaramond/ The last one (EB-Garamond) has a 1 that looks like a uppercase i. so I think ti's a possibility (and I like it :)

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a package, font, tool, book or other off-site resource** are off-topic as they usually do not revolve around an abstract issue.  Instead, [describe the problem](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Note that most of those come in more modern, OpenType versions, which are good options to use: GFS Neohellenic Math, XITS Math (for STIX), TeX Gyre Termes Math (for `txfonts`), and Garamond Math.

Comment: On my (macOS) computer, the font Gill Sans seems to fit: https://imgur.com/a/OTs88HZ (You can compile with `xelatex` or `lualatex` to use system fonts like this.) I don't know of a way to see font variation among “LaTeX” fonts (i.e. pdfTeX-compatible fonts, such as those in the LaTeX font catalogue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you load `fontspec`, you can use any regular old desktop font in LaTeX, as well as the TrueType and OpenType fonts that come with your TeX distribution.

You can check the fonts on your system with a character map application (such as `charmap.exe` on Windows).

If you care about math mode, which you might or might not if you’re writing a presentation for elementary-school children, the `unicode-math` package lets you also use OpenType math fonts.  Alternatively, `mathspec` lets you use a desktop font for letters and numbers, together with a legacy TeX math font.

For what it’s worth, there are several professional fonts designed not to confuse small children, including Sassoon and Gill Sans Infant, but they do not use this style for the numeral 1. Some kind of Grotesk would be your best bet.